# Понятие циклический палиндром

Tags: алгоритм, строки

Кто нибудь столкивался с понятием циклический палиндром ? Если нет такого понятия я удалю этот вопрос. Просто я столкнулся и мне интересно знать,что это такое .

Comment: Не встечал. Но если взять такое определение `Иногда палиндромом называют любой симметричный относительно своей середины набор символов` (из википедии), и представить себе этот набор записанный в циклический буфер, то если в нем будет более одной точки,  которую можно считать серединой, относительно которой набор симметричный, то такой набор, наверное, можно назвать *циклическим палиндромом*. В качестве вырожденного примера можно взять все символы одинаковыми.

Comment: @avp спасибо большое за информацию !

Comment: Циклическим его называют потому, что, будучи записанным по **окружности**, он может быть прочитан одинаково как по, так и против часовой стрелки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да есть такое понятие. Когда назад читается так же, но со сдвигом. Типа

*Наша лгала Глаша*

См. тут: http://www.inpearls.ru/463529

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию !

Comment: Да не за что :)